# Unable to move Desktop Files on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions, uac, windows-movie-maker

Has anyone come across an issue while running on Windows 7 Professional on a domain, where all the sudden they can no longer move around any files on the desktop?

What's even more weird is when I try to rename a file on the desktop I get a prompt saying that I need Administrative permissions to allow this. Being an administrator on the computer I can just press allow and the file is changed.

Im thinking this may be playing a role as to why I cannot move the files around on the desktop.

I don't know if this is just a coincidence but this all started once Windows Movie Maker was installed on the computer.

Has anyone ever experience this behaviour?

Comment: Speak to your domain admin and ask if they changed anything.

Comment: I am the domain admin and we have not changed anything.

Comment: Is the problem repeatable under a different username on that computer?

Comment: Check the permissions on your Desktop folder.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and back on?  Sorry just watched IT Crowd...  I deserve anything I get (i.e. yes I'm kidding).

Comment: I logged in with another user and then logged back in with the original user and this seemed to have resolved the being able to move the icons around. This however did not resolve the UAC prompt on renaming of the files. I've checked the permissions on the Desktop folder and the user has Full Control over the Desktop. As I mention when the UAC does pop-up they can simply "allow" to apply changes. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure you checked / applied the permissions recursively? @NickM.

Comment: The last time I saw something like that was because the domain admin locked down the Desktop of Public (or All users) so that domain users on a shared computer cannot modify standard shortcuts.